# $\left\lceil5n\right\rceil + 30n \geq 250$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Solve 
$\left\lceil5n\right\rceil + 30n \geq 250$ for $n$
(Show the lowest possible value)
$0\leq n \leq 10$

Can someone help me with this? I wrote a script in python and I discovered that the lowest value was $\frac{107}{15}$, but I still don't know how to solve this problem using only maths.

Comment: $ceil(5n)=5n$ if $n$ integer

Comment: What if 5n is not an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is confusing to use $n$ for what is apparently not an integer.

Prefer $x$ in this case.

So let $y=5x$ and the equation is $\lceil y\rceil+6y\ge 250$

- If $y$ is an integer then $\lceil y\rceil=y$

The equation becomes $\quad 7y\ge 250\iff y\ge 36\iff x\ge 7.2 $

- If $y$ is not an integer then $y=n+r$ with $n$ integer and $r\in]0,1[$.

The equation becomes $\quad n+1+6(n+r)\ge 250\iff 7n+6r\ge 249\iff \begin{cases} n\ge 35\\ 6r\ge249-7\times 35=4\end{cases}$ or $\begin{cases}n\ge 36\\r\ge 0\end{cases}$.

That is $y\ge 35+\frac 23\iff x\ge 7+\frac 2{15}=\frac{107}{15}\ $ or $y\ge 36$

The minimum value between $7.2$ and $\frac {107}{15}$ being the lattest, then this is the solution for the problem.

Comment: best answer so far ...

Answer (score 0):

The left side can only change when $n$ is a multiple of $\frac 1{30}$.  The ceiling function can increase the term, which decreases the $n$ required.  We can ignore the ceiling function, solve for $n$, then decrease $n$ in increments of $\frac 1{30}$ until we find the answer.  So
$$5n+30n=250\\n=\frac {250}{35}=\frac{50}7$$ is our upper bound.  Now just subtract off $\frac 1{30}$ at a time until $\lceil 5n \rceil+30n$ falls below $250$  This sort of piecewise linear function is more suitable to a bisection search than any other if you are doing basic root finding.

Comment: if f(n) = ceil(5*n)+30*n; f(50/7) ~= 250.28...; f(107/15) = 250

Comment: @Nacho:  that is exactly what I was saying.  We can guarantee that $f(\frac {50}7) \ge 250$  Now we try values decreasing by increments of $\frac 1{30}$ until we find the first where the function equals $250$. We don't have many to try.

Comment: Ok, but this is not that efficient.

Comment: @Nacho:  we won't have more than $6$ to try.  I think that is more efficient than thinking carefully about what we should try next. I judge the efficiency by the total of solver time and computer time.  If you have millions (billions?) of cases you should spend more solver time to reduce the computer time.  Otherwise, why bother?

Comment: yeah, but what if it took a billion steps? The fun part of maths is trying to do problems not by "bruteforcing".

Comment: It can't take a billion steps.  The increase of the ceiling  can't be more than $1$.  It can only take six steps.

Answer (score -1):

Let $n=I+f,0\le f<1$

If $f=0,\lceil n\rceil=I$

If $f>0,$

$$250=5(I+1)+30(I+f)$$

$$\iff35(7-I)/30=f$$

Now $0<f<1$